# Printing a multi-dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have this code in PHP:

```
$rules = array(
    "s0" => array(
        "a" => "s1_s2_s3",
        "b" => "s2_s3"    
    ),
    "s1_s2" => array(
        "a" => "s1_s2",
        "b" => "s2_s3"
    ),
);
```

And want to print it like this:

```
s0 -- a --- s1_s2_s3
s0 -- b --- s2_s3
s1_s2 -- a --- s1_s2
s1_s2 -- b --- s2_s3
```

How do I do it?

Comment: The amount of effort you put forth is amazing.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you do it:

```
$rules = array(
    "s0"  => array(
        "a" => "s1_s2_s3",
        "b" => "s2_s3"
    ),
    "s1_s2" => array(
        "a" => "s1_s2",
        "b" => "s2_s3"
    ),
);


foreach ($rules as $key => $args) {
    foreach ($args as $key2 => $vals) {
        print $key . ' -- ' . $key2 . ' --- ' . $vals . '<br>';
    }
}
```

**To edit the array**

You would use `array_push` or `[]`.

```
array_push($rules, ['another' => ['c' => 'value']]);
$rules['another'] = ['c' => 'value']];
```

To add or update to the array at an index:

```
$rules['another']['c'] = 'change c value';
```

Comment: thanks, i do it at same way as you, but i forgot on "value" :)

Comment: If it works for you, mark my answer as the right one please :-)

Comment: And one leas question. Is any array function, how i add new array value with these three "elements"? Something, like array_push?

Comment: May i do it, with variables?
for example:
    array_push($rules, [$state1 => [$alphabet => $state2]]);

Comment: Yes you can.  You should read up on arrays and data structures and variables.  http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you have to traverse the array. To do this, you need a loop, and in PHP, there is a function `foreach`. Here is the example-

**Given array:**

```
$rules = array("s0" => array("a" => "s1_s2_s3",
                              "b" => "s2_s3"    
                              ),
               "s1_s2" => array("a" => "s1_s2",
                                "b" => "s2_s3"
                               )
                );

foreach ($rules as $key => $value) {
    foreach ($value as $sub_key => $sub_val) {
        echo "<p>".$key." -- ".$sub_key." --- ".$sub_val."</p>";
    }
}
```

The foreach construct provides an easy way to iterate over arrays.

**Output:**

```
s0 -- a --- s1_s2_s3
s0 -- b --- s2_s3
s1_s2 -- a --- s1_s2
s1_s2 -- b --- s2_s3
```

Comment: thanks, i do it at same way as you, but i forgot on "value" :)